# Passing two Action<T> parameters and executing one of them based on the JSON result of an async API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, blazor, blazor-client-side

In my Blazor WASM application, I have written a (client-side) service class with a method to make an API call to the web API. The server will return either the expected result of `IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>` or a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails` object explaining what went wrong.

When calling the method, the UI (FetchData.razor) passes an `Action<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>` and an `Action<ProblemDetails>`. Only one of these actions should ever be executed, depending on what is returned by the server. This allows the service class to choose what to do based on the deserialized JSON result of the API call.

Usage (in FetchData.razor):

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@using BlazorApp1.Shared
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject WeatherForecastsService Service

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Service.GetAllAsync(
            success => forecasts = success,
            problem => Console.WriteLine("Handle this problem: " + problem.Detail));
    }

}
```

My attempt at implementation, below, does not work. I am sure that the API call is reaching the correct API endpoint and getting JSON back, but my razor page is not getting populated with the WeatherForecasts and it is not writing the problem detail to the console either. Debugging in Blazor WASM (though much improved) is still quite difficult.

I have been fiddling with this code for days but have failed. Can anybody help me see what I am doing wrong please?

```
    public class WeatherForecastsService : ServiceBase
    {
        public WeatherForecastsService(
            HttpClient client) : base(client)
        {

        }

        public async Task GetAllAsync(
            Action<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> actionOnSuccess,
            Action<ProblemDetails> actionOnFailure,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            await GetManyAsync("weatherforecast",
                actionOnSuccess,
                actionOnFailure,
                cancellationToken);
        }
    }

   public abstract class ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceBase(HttpClient client)
        {
            Client = client;
        }

        protected HttpClient Client
        {
            get;
        }


        protected virtual async Task GetManyAsync<TExpected>(
            string path,
            Action<IEnumerable<TExpected>> actionOnSuccess,
            Action<ProblemDetails> actionOnProblem,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            where TExpected : class
        {
            string json = await GetJsonAsync(path, cancellationToken);
            ProblemDetails? problem = Deserialize<ProblemDetails>(json);

            if (problem is { })
            {
                var taskOnProblem = TaskFromAction(actionOnProblem, problem);
                await taskOnProblem;
            }
            else
            {
                IEnumerable<TExpected>? expected = Deserialize<IEnumerable<TExpected>>(json);
                expected = EnsureNotNull(expected);

                var taskOnSuccess = TaskFromAction(actionOnSuccess, expected);
                await taskOnSuccess;
            }
        }

        private Task TaskFromAction<T>(Action<T> action, T state)
        {
            return new Task(ActionOfObjectFromActionOfT(action), state);
        }

        private Action<object> ActionOfObjectFromActionOfT<T>(Action<T> actionOfT)
        {
            return new Action<object>(o => actionOfT((T)o));
        }

        private IEnumerable<T> EnsureNotNull<T>(IEnumerable<T>? enumerable)
        {
            if (enumerable is null)
            {
                enumerable = new List<T>();
            }

            return enumerable;
        }

        private async Task<string> GetJsonAsync(string path, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var response = await Client.GetAsync(path, cancellationToken);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }


        private T? Deserialize<T>(string json)
            where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, null);
            }
            catch (JsonException)
            {
                return default;
            }
        }
    }
```

A minimal reproducible example of my failed attempt at this problem can be found here:
https://github.com/BenjaminCharlton/AsyncBlazorRepro

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Henk, thanks for your interest! The best result I have got in the browser so far is to see it display the right number of WeatherForecasts but for their string properties to all be blank and their date properties all show `DateTime.MinValue`.
`TaskFromAction` was one of several experiments I tried to make this work because I thought the problem might be related to synchronicity so I tried running the actions asynchronously instead. I also tried passing a `Func<TExpected, Task>` instead of an `Action<TExpected>` which worked no better or worse.

Comment: Got it! :-D I was peering closely at the browser console like you requested and noticed something I hadn't thought about before: nothing. There was nothing there. So I started to think about what was happening under the covers that I didn't control: deserialization. The methods in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HttpClientJsonExtensions` all pass a `JsonSerializerOptions` to the `Deserialize` method, but in my code I was just passing `null` because I didn't think it was important. The `JsonSerializer` was ignoring every single property because of case-sensitivity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

This problem had nothing to do with async-await problems. It was all to do with deserialization problems.

Looking at the ASP .NET Core source code here:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Blazor/Http/src/HttpClientJsonExtensions.cs

You'll notice that the methods in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HttpClientJsonExtensions` all pass a `JsonSerializerOptions` to the `Deserialize` method, but in my code I was just passing null because I didn't think it was important. The `JsonSerializer` was ignoring every single property because of case-sensitivity!

I changed my Deserialize method as below:

```
       private T? Deserialize<T>(string json)
            where T : class
        {
            var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
            {
                PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
            };

            try
            {
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, jsonOptions);
            }
            catch (JsonException)
            {
                return default;
            }
        }
```

As Henk pointed out in the comments, I had also written in some unnecessary complexity. I didn't need to turn the `Action`s into `Task`s using my pointless `TaskFromAction` method. You can just leave them as `Action`s. You can also create an overload that takes `Func<TExpected, Task>` if you want to give callers an asynchronous option too.

I have updated the repro project on GitHub with working code in case anybody else wishes to encapsulate their Blazor API calls this way.

https://github.com/BenjaminCharlton/AsyncBlazorRepro